# Export data from R to Excel

Tags: r, excel, r-faq

I am writing code to export database from R into Excel, I have been trying others code including:

```
write.table(ALBERTA1, "D:/ALBERTA1.txt", sep="\t")
write.csv(ALBERTA1,":\ALBERTA1.csv")
your_filename_in_R = read.csv("ALBERTA1.csv")
your_filename_in_R = read.csv("ALBERTA1.csv")
write.csv(df, file = "ALBERTA1.csv")
your_filename_in_R = read.csv("ALBERTA1.csv")
write.csv(ALBERTA1, "ALBERTA1.csv")
write.table(ALBERTA1, 'clipboard', sep='\t')
write.table(ALBERTA1,"ALBERTA1.txt")
write.table(as.matrix(ALBERTA2),"ALBERTA2.txt")
write.table(as.matrix(vecm.pred$fcst$Alberta_Females[,1]), "vecm.pred$fcst$Alberta_Females[,1].txt")
write.table(as.matrix(foo),"foo.txt")
write.xlsx(ALBERTA2, "/ALBERTA2.xlsx")
write.table(ALBERTA1, "D:/ALBERTA1.txt", sep="\t").
```

Other users of this forum advised me this:

```
write.csv2(ALBERTA1, "ALBERTA1.csv")
write.table(kt, "D:/kt.txt", sep="\t", row.names=FALSE)
```

[image]

You can see on the pictures the outcome I have got from the code above. But this numbers can't be used to make any further operations such as addition with other matrices.

Has someone experienced this kind of problems?

Comment: If you don't post output of `dput(ALBERTA1)` or `dput(head(ALBERTA1))` we will not be able to help. There would be too much guesswork.

Comment: Note that this is apparently a follow up on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19385494/324364) question.

Comment: The first 6 numbers on RGUI interface are the following: 55.5486398,  57.8471114,  54.5190511,  50.5751821,  49.4739451,  53.4697459. You can check out that there is a short decimal part of each output. However, when i transfer the same list of numbers on Excel through codes presented above,  I obtain the following unclear shape of output: 555.486.398.454.784, 578.471.113.839.479, 54.519.051.119.506, 49.473.945.115.391, 534.697.459.336.592, 505.751.821.039.884..etc of course unmanageable 
You can see that 555.486.398.454.784(in excel) is totally different from 55.5486398(R-gui interface).

Answer (score 93):

Another option is the `openxlsx`-package. It doesn't depend on [java](/questions/tagged/java) and can read, edit and write *Excel*-files. From the description from the package:

> openxlsx simplifies the the process of writing and styling Excel xlsx files from R and removes the dependency on Java

Example usage:

```
library(openxlsx)

# read data from an Excel file or Workbook object into a data.frame
df <- read.xlsx('name-of-your-excel-file.xlsx')

# for writing a data.frame or list of data.frames to an xlsx file
write.xlsx(df, 'name-of-your-excel-file.xlsx')
```

Besides these two basic functions, the `openxlsx`-package has a host of other functions for manipulating *Excel*-files.

For example, with the `writeDataTable`-function you can create formatted tables in an *Excel*-file.

Comment: `openxlsx` depends on Rtools, which need to be installed and added to the System variables path. Not ideal for corporate computers. I use this and now trying to find alternatives as I need to make portable versions of my code which work without installing anything.

Comment: @Arani I highly doubt that. I have installed `openxlsx` on a Windows VM  without having Rtools and it works as it should.

Comment: in my case it does everything except `saveWorkbook`, or `write.xlsx`. For that it asks for Rtools. Mysterious!

Comment: @jaap some functions depends of Rtools but not all

Comment: @DimitriPetrenko Could you indicate which functions? If haven't run into that problem yet and I use this package quite often (and a lot / most of its functions)

Comment: @Jaap yes check this page https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/111

Comment: this library is not updated since I get this warning --> `Note: zip::zip() is deprecated, please use zip::zipr() instead`

Comment: A great option, as it also allows to write multi-sheet excel-files (which does not seem to be possible with openxlsx (but also worked with xlsx package originally))

Answer (score 41):

Recently used xlsx package, works well.

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(x, file, sheetName="Sheet1")
```

where x is a data.frame

Comment: `xlsx` requires Java. If for whatever reason it is not accessible by R (strange settings on corporate computers), then this won't work.

Comment: Add jre path of java into System variables Path, then R can access Java functionalities. For this go to My computer Properties, then Advanced System Settings, and then environment variables. Add java path to "Path".

Answer (score 29):

[`writexl`](https://github.com/ropensci/writexl), without Java requirement:

```
# install.packages("writexl")
library(writexl)
tempfile <- write_xlsx(iris)
```

Comment: Unfortunately not great for corporate computers either: 
"Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘writexl’
  These will not be installed"

Comment: @JulianDrago Can't you compile it on a non-corporate computer?

Comment: Not an option for me, and for many others judging by the comments on this question.  My comment is intended to be a heads up to those of us that this may not work in firewalled/non-admin user work environments - I suspect that many of us are here for that reason, looking for alternatives to the popular xlsx package that might work.

Answer (score 11):

The *WriteXLS* function from the [WriteXLS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WriteXLS/index.html) package can write data to Excel.

Alternatively, *write.xlsx* from the [xlsx](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/) package will also work.

Comment: `xlsx` requires Java. `WriteXLS` requires Perl. If for whatever reason these are not accessible by R (I cannot that easily choose what to install on my corporate computer), then neither of these will work. (I understand it is convenient for the developers to rely on the existing Java and Perl libraries; but isn't R supposed to stand on its own legs??)

Comment: `writeXLS` can't deal with newlines in characters.

Answer (score 2):

One could also use the [readODS](https://github.com/chainsawriot/readODS) package. Granted it doesn't produce an `.xlsx`, but Excel can read Open Document Spreadsheet (ODS) / LibreOffice files too.

```r
require(readODS)

tmp = file.path(tempdir(), 'iris.ods')
write_ods(iris, tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I might offer an alternative, you could also save your dataframe in a regular `csv` file, and then use the "get data" function within Excel to import the dataframe. This worked like a charm for me, and you need not bother with any excel packages in R.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a way to write data from a dataframe into an excel file **by** different IDs and into different tabs (sheets) by another ID associated to the first level id. Imagine you have a dataframe that has `email_address` as one column for a number of different users, but each email has a number of 'sub-ids' that have all the data.

```
data <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), email_address = c(rep('aaa@aaa.com',3), rep('bbb@bbb.com', 3), rep('ccc@ccc.com', 3)))
```

So ids `1,2,3` would be associated with `aaa@aaa.com`. The following code splits the data by email and then puts `1,2,3` into different tabs. The important thing is to set `append = True` when writing the `.xlsx` file.

```
temp_dir <- tempdir()

for(i in unique(data$email_address)){
    
  data %>% 
    filter(email_address == i) %>% 
    arrange(id) -> subset_data
  
  for(j in unique(subset_data$id)){
    write.xlsx(subset_data %>% filter(id == j), 
      file = str_c(temp_dir,"/your_filename_", str_extract(i, pattern = "\\b[A-Za-z0- 
       9._%+-]+"),'_', Sys.Date(), '.xlsx'), 
      sheetName = as.character(j), 
      append = TRUE)}
 
  }
```

The regex gets the name from the email address and puts it into the file-name.

Hope somebody finds this useful. I'm sure there's more elegant ways of doing this but it works.

Btw, here is a way to then send these individual files to the various email addresses in the `data.frame`. Code goes into second loop `[j]`

```
  send.mail(from = "sender@sender.com",
            to = i,
          subject = paste("Your report for", str_extract(i, pattern = "\\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+"), 'on', Sys.Date()),
          body = "Your email body",
          authenticate = TRUE,
          smtp = list(host.name = "XXX", port = XXX,
                      user.name = Sys.getenv("XXX"), passwd = Sys.getenv("XXX")),
          attach.files = str_c(temp_dir, "/your_filename_", str_extract(i, pattern = "\\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+"),'_', Sys.Date(), '.xlsx'))
```

Answer (score -5):

I have been trying out the different packages including the function:

```
install.packages ("prettyR") 

library (prettyR)
```

`delimit.table (Corrvar,"Name the csv.csv")` `## Corrvar` is a name of an object from an output I had on scaled variables to run a regression.

However I tried this same code for an output from another analysis (occupancy models model selection output) and it did not work. And after many attempts and exploration I:

- copied the output from R (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>)
- in Excel sheet I pasted it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)
- Select the first column where the data is
- In the "Data" vignette, click on "Text to column"
- Select Delimited option, click next
- Tick space box in "Separator", click next
- Click Finalize (End)

Your output now should be in a form you can manipulate easy in excel. So perhaps not the fanciest option but it does the trick if you just want to explore your data in another way.

PS. If the labels in excel are not the exact one it is because Im translating the lables from my spanish excel.