# How to store loop table data

Tags: r, for-loop

I am a newbie in R. Could somebody please help me with this problem? I want to store the loop table data and export it into excel file, but I have not succeeded. Thanks.

```
Qquest7 <- c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A")
Qquest24 <- c("neutral", "somewhat satisfied", "somewhat satisfied", "not able to rate", "somewhat satisfied", "less satisfied", "not able to rate", "dissatisfied", "very satisfied", "dissatisfied")
Qquest25 <- c("not able to rate", "not able to rate", "not able to rate", "somewhat satisfied", "not able to rate", "not able to rate", "dissatisfied", "dissatisfied", "not able to rate", "very satisfied")
Qquest26 <- c("not able to rate", "somewhat satisfied", "not able to rate", "less satisfied", "not able to rate", "neutral", "somewhat satisfied", "neutral", "neutral", "somewhat satisfied")
Qquest27 <- c("very satisfied", "not able to rate", "somewhat satisfied", "neutral", "very satisfied", "neutral", "neutral", "somewhat satisfied", "neutral", "not able to rate")
Qquest28 <- c("not able to rate", "not able to rate", "not able to rate", "not able to rate", "not able to rate", "not able to rate", "very satisfied", "neutral", "somewhat satisfied", "neutral")
Qquest29 <- c("desktop", "laptop", "tablet", "cellphone", "desktop", "desktop", "tablet", "laptop", "cellphone", "laptop")        

df <- data.frame(Qquest7, Qquest24, Qquest25, Qquest26, Qquest27, Qquest28, Qquest29)

library(openxlsx)
trial2429 <- c("Qquest24","Qquest25", "Qquest26", "Qquest27", "Qquest28", "Qquest29")
x <- data.frame()
y <- data.frame()
for (i in df[trial2429]){
  x[i] <- table(df$Qquest7, i)
  y <- print(x)
}
write.xlsx(y, file = "trial2429.xlsx")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export data to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414605/export-data-to-excel)

Comment: What does "not succeeded" exactly mean? What is the error/problem?

Comment: The problem is if I add the index [i] after x, it does not produce the result but give me an error message instead "Error in value[[jvseq[[jjj]]]] : subscript out of bounds". If I remove [i], everything works fine. Multiple tables can be printed in the console but I do not know how to export it into csv or excel as only 1 table appears in the generated excel file.

Comment: @SeanPianka: I do not think so

Comment: Can you add some example data to make this reproducible?

Comment: @LukeC: I added the data

Comment: Awesome, thanks. So- how do you expect the output to be stored in your `y` data.frame, in terms of structure? The `table` for the different questions produces different variable/column names, so I'm not sure exactly what your desired output is.

Comment: What is your desired result? All tables in one? Different sheets?

Comment: @LukeC: thank you so much. It is solved and the solution is more complicated than I thought.

Comment: @Parfait: my desired result is the one below in the answer section.

Comment: @Nann - no problem, glad I guessed correctly. I'm sure there is a direct-to-excel version, but I haven't seen it before. Cheers!

Comment: @LukeC: I do not understand why you had to name trial2429. Is it not already a variable name?

Comment: Good catch- honestly it's just a holdover from the way I was using this function in my own work- with the way your data is setup you could probably modify the function to not need it. However, to clarify- it's not naming `trial2429`, it's assigning names to the values within `trial2429` so that the `lapply` function has named objects as input and therefore names for the objects it outputs. The `export_results` function here actually needs a list with named objects as input to work.

Comment: @LukeC: thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% what you're after as desired output, but this function I've used for my own purposes might do the trick for you. Using your `df` and `trial2429` for data, first give `trial2429` some names:

```
names(trial2429) <- trial2429
```

Now, build a function that takes a list and sequentially adds its contents to a .csv file:

```
## Export list
export_results <- function(df_list, file_name = "outfile.csv") {
  if (file.exists(file_name)) {
    file.remove(file_name)
    print("Removed old file.")
  }

  ## Clean export function
  writeout <- function(table_name) {
    write(table_name, file_name, sep = ",", append = TRUE)
    tab.out <- df_list[[table_name]]
    tab.out <- cbind(rownames(tab.out), tab.out)
    write.table(
      tab.out,
      file_name,
      row.names = FALSE,
      sep = ",",
      append = TRUE
    )
    write("", file_name, sep = ",", append = TRUE)
  }

  for (i in names(df_list)) {
    writeout(i)
  }
}
```

Get the table version for each question that you're after, and store it in a list:

```
q.list <- lapply(trial2429, function(x){
  table(df$Qquest7, df[[x]])
})
```

Call the function defined above on that list:

```
export_results(q.list, file_name = "trial2429.csv")
```

It'll throw some warning messages, but it seems to not cause any problems- your output should like this in Excel:

[image]

**Edit: Fixed number-of-columns issue**