# Is there a way to accelerate formatted table writing from R to excel?

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I have a 174603 rows and 178 column dataframe, which I'm importing to Excel using openxlsx::saveWorkbook, (Using this package to obtain the aforementioned format of cells, with colors, header styles and so on). But the process is extremely slow, (depending on the amount of memory used by the machine it can take from 7 to 17 minutes!!) and I need a way to reduce this significantly (Doesn't need to be seconds, but anything bellow 5 min would be OK)

I've already searched other questions but they all seem to focus either in exporting to R (I have no problem with this) or writing non-formatted files to R (using write.csv and other options of the like)

Apparently I can't use xlsx package because of the settings on my computer (industrial computer, Check comments on [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414605/export-data-from-r-to-excel))

Any suggestions regarding packages or other functionalities inside this package to make this run faster would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really have a `data.frame` in R or is it already a `workbook`-object? If it is a `data.frame`, `write.xlsx` should be faster than `saveWorkbook`

Comment: @Juialn_Hn why do you think `write.xlsx` is faster than `saveWorkbook`? Afaik `write.xlsx` calls `saveWorkbook` and thus cannot be faster.

Comment: @Julian_Hn The user selects the file from a fileInput and I read it as data frame `file1 <- data.frame(read.xlsx(file1$datapath))` I perform required operations over said data frame. I create a Workbook `wb <- createWorkbook()` add a sheet `addWorksheet(wb,...)` write the data into the Workbook `writeDataTable(wb,1,file1,...)` add the required styles `addStyle(wb,...)` and then comes the problem...`saveWorkbook(wb,file = path,overwrite=TRUE)`

Comment: @AEF: you are right. I had it remembered the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

This question has some time ,but I had the same problem as you and came up with a solution worth mentioning.
There is package called **writexl** that has implemented a way to export a data frame to Excel using the **C** library **libxlsxwriter**. You can export to excel using the next code:

```
library(writexl)
writexl::write_xlsx(df, "Excel.xlsx",format_headers = TRUE)
```

The parameter **format_headers** only apply centered and bold titles, but I had edited the C code of the its source in github [writexl library](https://github.com/ropensci/writexl) made by ropensci.
You can download it or clone it. Inside **src** folder you can edit **write_xlsx.c** file.

For example in the part that he is inserting the header format

> //how to format headers (bold + center)
>
> lxw_format * title = workbook_add_format(workbook);
>
> format_set_bold(title);
>
> format_set_align(title, LXW_ALIGN_CENTER);

you can add this lines to add background color to the header

> format_set_pattern (title, LXW_PATTERN_SOLID);
>
> format_set_bg_color(title, 0x8DC4E4);

There are lots of formating you can do searching in the **libxlsxwriter** library

When you have finished editing that file and given you have the source code in a folder called **writexl**, you can build and install the edited package by

```
shell("R CMD build writexl")
install.packages("writexl_1.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
```

Exporting again using the first chunk of code will generate the Excel with formats and faster than any other library I know about.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried ;

```
write.table(GroupsAlldata, file = 'Groupsalldata.txt')
```

in order to obtain it in txt format.
Then on Excel, you can simply transfer you can 'text to column' to put your data into a table
good luck

Comment: His problem is concerned with formatted tables. You will lose the formatting with `write.table`

Comment: @Mohammed Ahmed As Jualin pointed out, I can't loose the format when i export to excel