# collecting data downloaded with the package gtrendsR into excel

Tags: r

Good morning everyone, 
I imported data from google trends using the package gtrendsR. How can I bring those data into one file excel?

Comment: Use `write.csv()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export data from R to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414605/export-data-from-r-to-excel)