# What R function can help me to select and export a column from a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataset, export-to-excel

I have already imported my SAS dataset to R with the `haven` package. Now I need to extract some of the columns from the data and export them to an excel file.

Comment: Where are you having issues specifically? There are several options for exporting to Excel, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414605/export-data-from-r-to-excel

Comment: If the data is successfully imported into R and you want to go to Excel, then your question has nothing to do with SAS, unless it has some special structure or class because of how the `haven` package imported it. It it does, and that makes the standard Excel export tools have problems, please make your example reproducible by sharing some sample data with `dput()` and sharing the code you've tried. However, if it is a standard `data.frame`, then the solutions in the FAQ about Excel exports should work.

Comment: If you're not familiar with SAS or R, I would suggest downloading the SAS Universal Viewer which allows you to export the data to a CSV directly which you can then filter in Excel as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already imported the file to R, let's assume that you saved it in a dataframe called `df`.

Then, you can select the rows you want, and save the results to a new dataframe called `df2` with the `select` command from the `tidyverse` package. Just put the variables' names you want separeted by commas:

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>% select(var1, var2, var3)
```

After that, you can export the new dataframe to a .csv file, which you may open in Excel:

```
write.csv(df2,"C:\\Users\\Ary\\Desktop\\MyData.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it worked for you. You just need to click the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work