# How to create a new data file from an existing dataset to load into Rattle?

Tags: r, decision-tree, rattle

My goal is to create a decision tree model in Rattle for a school project. I've been able to determine the variables that I would need for my research question and created a new dataset from the original .csv file. After saving the new dataset as not only an .xls file and a .rdata file, I received an error message after loading the file into Rattle. This is my first time creating a decision tree model so I'm struggling a bit. Thanks in advance for your help!

Here's what I have so far:

```
install.packages(readxl)

library(readxl)
library(rattle)

setwd("C:/Users/river/OneDrive/Documents/Random Data")

edu <- read_excel('pfi_pu.xlsx')



eduu <- data.frame(c("P1HRSWK" = c(edu$P1HRSWK),
                   "P1EMPL" = c(edu$P1EMPL),
                   "P2HRSWK" = c(edu$P2HRSWK),
                   "P2EMPL" = c(edu$P2EMPL),
                   "P1ENRL" = c(edu$P1ENRL),
                   "P2ENRL" = c(edu$P2ENRL),
                   "P1EDUC" = c(edu$P1EDUC),
                   "P2EDUC" = c(edu$P2EDUC),
                   "P1HISPRM" = c(edu$P1HISPRM),
                   "P2HISPRM" = c(edu$P2HISPRM),
                   "P1PACI" = c(edu$P1PACI),
                   "P2PACI" = c(edu$P2PACI),
                   "P1BLACK" = c(edu$P1BLACK),
                   "P2BLACK" = c(edu$P2BLACK),
                   "P1ASIAN" = c(edu$P1ASIAN),
                   "P2ASIAN" = c(edu$P2ASIAN),
                   "P1AMIND" = c(edu$P1AMIND),
                   "P2AMIND" = c(edu$P2AMIND),
                   "P1HISPAN" = c(edu$P1HISPAN),
                   "P2HISPAN" = c(edu$P2HISPAN),
                   "P1LKWRK" = c(edu$P1LKWRK),
                   "P2LKWRK" = c(edu$P2LKWRK),
                   "P1MTHSWRK" = c(edu$P1MTHSWRK),
                   "P1REL" = c(edu$P1REL),
                   "P2REL" = c(edu$P2REL),
                   "P1SEX" = c(edu$P1SEX),
                   "P2SEX" = c(edu$P2SEX),
                   "P1MRSTA" = c(edu$P1MRSTA),
                   "SEFUTUREX" = c(edu$SEFUTUREX),
                   "HSFUTUREX" = c(edu$HSFUTUREX),
                   "PARGRADEX" = c(edu$PARGRADEX),
                   "TTLHHINC" = c(edu$TTLHHINC),
                   "PAR1EMPL" = c(edu$PAR1EMPL),
                   "PAR2EMPL" = c(edu$PAR2EMPL),
                   "SEEXPEL" = c(edu$SEEXPEL),
                   "SESUSPIN" = c(edu$SESUSPIN),
                   "SESUSOUT" = c(edu$SESUSOUT),
                   "SEGRADEQ" = c(edu$SEGRADEQ)
                    ,dim = c(14075,38,1))


save(eduu,file="eduu.xls")
```

error message

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems your problem is about writing a file. The command `save` must be used to save .RData files, not Excel files. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414605/export-data-from-r-to-excel) post, you may try:

```r
openxlsx::write.xlsx(eduu, 'eduu.xlsx')
```

```r
xlsx::write.xlsx(eduu, 'eduu.xlsx')
```

```r
writexl::write_xlsx(eduu, 'eduu.xlsx')
```