# How to copy data.table output from Jupyter notebook to Excel

Tags: r, excel, jupyter-notebook, data.table

I'm using Jupyter notebook to work with R and data.table. The problem is I cannot properly copy table outputs to Excel or any other software. In Python I would use `to_clipboard()` but I found no such function for R's data.table.

At the moment I'm exporting to CSV and importing the CSV in Excel, which is rather inefficient.

Comment: Wouldn't the `writexl` R package work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414605/export-data-from-r-to-excel